# C stdio program built by Xcode generates "cannot execute binary file: Exec format error" on Ubuntu

Tags: xcode, ubuntu, x86-64

I last built this console I/O program with Xcode years ago, haven't used Xcode since, and today fumbled my way through re-building the program. It works fine on my mid-2014 Macbook Pro. But when I copy it to a remote x86_64 VPS running Ubuntu, running it generates the cited error message. In Xcode (current release) the architecture in Build Settings::Architectures is 64-bit Intel. What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

macOS and Linux (Ubuntu, in your case) use different executable file formats. macOS uses Mach-O; Linux uses ELF. You can't run an executable built for macOS on Linux or vice versa.